# mysql trigger on update with insert statement

Tags: mysql, trigger

I am trying to create a simple trigger which is handled on update operations. The trigger is checking before update if a record of an update exists, then if not it is created.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER trig
BEFORE UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF old is null then
INSERT INTO table(table.col1, table.col2) VALUES ('new.table.col1','new.table.col2');
END IF;
END;
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Why is it not adding a record if update is trying to update some non existing record?

Comment: Read this answer about why `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is usually better than `REPLACE`, especially if you have foreign key constraints: **[`INSERT IGNORE` vs `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` vs `REPLACE`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't need a trigger at all and - based on your comments - you want an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. If there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(col2)`, this will work:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
  (col1, col2) 
VALUES 
  (@col1, @col2)                  -- the new values here
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  col1 = col1 + VALUES(col1) ;    -- update the old value by adding the new one
```

Comment: Yees thats exactly what i needed. That works great, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).

Try this:

```
REPLACE INTO table(table.col1, table.col2) VALUES (value1, value2);
```

No need for a trigger at all.

Comment: Big thanks for u. Solved.
If someone haves similar problem and it seems for him that solution not works, that means u dont use query properly. Replace use primary keys if u r not using primary key in query it works like insert statement.

Comment: :( nooo it is not working because the replace ain suport the incrementation.
I need to use it like:
    REPLACE INTO table(table.col1, table.col2) VALUES (OLD.Value=OLD.value+value1, value2);
but the replace dont see the OLD.value

Comment: @user2226087 I suggest you edit your question and add the structure of the table (the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`) and an example of what you want to happen when there is a duplicate.